# Send Ajax "application/json" POST with CSRF

Tags: javascript, apache, csrf

I've tried to send POST like this with enabled CSRF:

```
var emp = { Name: "anuraj", Email: "anuraj@server.com", Phone: "938944" };
   return jQuery.ajax("/myController.controller", {
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(emp),
        dataType: "json"
    });
```

But unfortunatly I get the following error in apache log:

```
mod_parp(010): parser error, rc=500 (No parser available for this content type (application/json)), referer: https://localhost/myController.controller
```

How can I send such request with enabled CSRF?

Comment: perhaps you can use escape(JSON.stringify(emp)) before send this to server, then unescape and json parse it at server side.

Comment: I am not sure that I undestand your point. I can't send any data with "application/json" content type. Apache blocks such requests, as result I won't be able to unescape any data on server side.